# Simple toggle function in Vue trigger: You may have an infinite update loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have read a few answers about infinite update loop and still don't understand the issue.

I still keep getting this error message:

`[Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.`

What is the correct Vue way to write simple toggle function? Looks like my approach is just wrong.

```
<template>
    <v-content>
      <v-container fluid fill-height>
        <v-layout align-center justify-center>
            <v-btn
                color="normal"
                :click="toggleLogin()"
                >
                {{login ? "Register" : "Login"}}
            </v-btn>
        </v-layout>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: () => ({
        login: true
    }),
    methods: {
        toggleLogin: function() {
            console.log(this.login)
            this.login = !this.login
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change data binding

```
:click="toggleLogin()"
```

to event handling:

```
@click="toggleLogin()"
```

Comment: Solved! I understand what is the issue now, thank you very much.